# iOS 9.3 Interactive pop gesture corrupts navigation bar

Tags: ios, navigationbar, ios9.3, interactivepopgesture

I have an iOS app with interactive pop gesture enabled by default, however when I play with it sometimes it comes to corrupt navigation bar but popping by tap on back buttons works good, any ideas?

[image]